# How to go about this complex number question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Hello I am trying to find out the cases in which $$z+\frac{1}{z}$$ and $$z \in \mathbb{C}$$ is real.

Here is what I have tried.
Knowing that z is real iff its imaginary part is 0.

$$z+\frac{1}{z}=R$$

$$\frac{z^2+1}{z}=R$$

$$\frac{(a^2-b^2+(2ab)i+1)}{a+bi}=R$$

But I dont know what I could do next
Also, I know from the definition of 1/z with $z=a+bi$

and $z$ is not zero then $1/z$ is $$\frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}$$

so $$z+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{(a^2+b^2)(a+bi)+(a-bi)}{a^2+b^2}$$

But again I dont know what to do next. Can anyone help me with this? Are either of my approaches on the right path? Thanks

Comment: Hint:  Assume $$z+\frac 1z = \overline z +\frac 1{\overline z}$$.  Then we get $$z-\overline z =\frac {1}{\overline z}-\frac 1z$$.  Now combine the terms on the right.

Comment: @Quality. Nice question. You do realize though that you were very close to Dr.MV's answer? Work out your numerator and consider the imaginary terms...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want

$$\text{Im}\left(z+\frac1z\right)=0$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\text{Im}\left(z+\frac1z\right)&=\text{Im}\left((a+ib)+\frac1{a+ib}\right)\\\\
&=\text{Im}\left((a+ib)+\frac{a-ib}{a^2+b^2}\right)\\\\
&=b-\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}\\\\
&=0\implies \,\,b=0\,\,,\text{or}\,\,a^2+b^2=1\implies \bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{|z|=1\,\,\text{or}\,\,\text{Im}(z)=0}
\end{align}$$

Comment: sharp, yet simple...+1

Comment: @imranfat Thanks!! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be real, a complex number $\omega$ must satisfy $\overline \omega = \omega$. Thus, here, we want $$z +\frac 1z = \overline z + \frac 1{\overline z}$$  Rewrite to get $$z-\overline z=\frac 1{\overline z} - \frac 1z =\frac {z-\overline z}{z\overline z}$$.

One case is that $z - \overline z=0$ which is equivalent to $z\in \mathbb R$.

Excluding that we can divide by $z-\overline z$ to get $$1=\frac 1{z\overline z}\;\Rightarrow\;z\overline z = 1$$

Hence, either $z$ is real or $z$ lies on the unit circle (or both).